# Dynamic programming with two parameters: days and coupons

Tags: algorithm, go, dynamic-programming

There is a cafe that has the following discount system: for each purchase of **more** than $100, the buyer receives a coupon that gives the right to one free lunch.
You have a price list for the next N days like:

```
5
35
40
101
59
63
```

**The price limitation: 0 ≤ price ≤ 300**

Find the minimum possible total cost of lunches and the numbers of days on which you should use the coupons.

Please help to stabilize DP fulfilling. I am not sure the initial DP table is suitable for the task so I can not handle edge cases correctly:

```
func main() {
    file, _ := os.ReadFile("input.txt")

    lines := strings.Split(string(file), "\n")

    p := make([]int, 0, len(lines))

    for i := 0; i < len(lines); i++ {
        price, err := strconv.Atoi(lines[i])

        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        p = append(p, price)
    }

    dp := make([][]int, len(p)+1)
    dp[0] = make([]int, len(dp))
    
    // zero day row
    for i := 1; i < len(dp); i++ {
        // no coupons on the first day visit
        dp[0][i] = math.MaxInt32
    }
    
    // 1...N days
    for i := 1; i < len(dp); i++ {
        dp[i] = make([]int, len(p))
    }

    for i := 1; i <= len(p); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(p); j++ {
            if p[i-1] <= 100 {
                dp[i][j] = Min(dp[i-1][j]+p[i-1], dp[i-1][j+1])
            }

            dp[i][j] = Min(dp[i-1][j-1]+p[i-1], dp[i-1][j+1])
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(dp)
}

func Min(i, j int) int {
    if i <= j {
        return i
    }

    return j
}
```

Thank you.

Upd. Extended solution which seems to achieve the best results but is unaccepted by 3rt party testing system:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    file, _ := os.ReadFile("input.txt")

    lines := strings.Split(string(file), "\n")

    p := make([]int, 0, len(lines))

    for i := 1; i < len(lines); i++ {
        price, err := strconv.Atoi(lines[i])

        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        p = append(p, price)
    }

    l := len(p)

    dp := make([][]int, l+1)
    dp[0] = make([]int, len(dp))

    for i := 1; i < len(dp); i++ {
        dp[0][i] = math.MaxInt32
    }

    for i := 1; i < len(dp); i++ {
        dp[i] = make([]int, l+1)
    }

    // fill dp
    for i := 1; i <= l; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= l; j++ {
            if p[i-1] <= 100 {
                if j == l {
                    dp[i][j] = MinOrZero(dp[i-1][j]+p[i-1], dp[i-1][j])
                    continue
                }

                dp[i][j] = MinOrZero(dp[i-1][j]+p[i-1], dp[i-1][j+1])
                continue
            }

            if j == 0 {
                dp[i][j] = MinOrZero(math.MaxInt32, dp[i-1][j+1])
                continue
            }

            if j == l {
                dp[i][j] = MinOrZero(dp[i-1][j-1]+p[i-1], dp[i-1][j])
                continue
            }

            dp[i][j] = MinOrZero(dp[i-1][j-1]+p[i-1], dp[i-1][j+1])
        }
    }
    
    // coupons left
    coupons := 0
    min := math.MaxInt

    for j := l; j >= 0; j-- {
        sum := dp[l][j]

        if sum < min {
            min = sum
            coupons = j
        }
    }

    couponDays := make([]int, 0)
    j := coupons
    sum := min

    for i := l; i > 0; i-- {
        jl := j - 1
        js := j
        jr := j + 1

        if jr < l && dp[i-1][jr] == sum {
            couponDays = append(couponDays, i)
            j++
            continue
        }

        if dp[i-1][js] == sum {
            sum = dp[i-1][js]
            continue
        }

        if jl >= 0 && dp[i-1][jl] == sum-p[i-1] {
            sum = dp[i-1][jl]
            j--
            continue
        }

        sum -= p[i-1]
    }

    sort.Ints(couponDays)

    fmt.Println(min)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%d %d", coupons, len(couponDays)))
    for _, day := range couponDays {
        fmt.Println(day)
    }
}

func Min(i, j int) int {
    if i <= j {
        return i
    }

    return j
}

func MinOrZero(i, j int) int {
    var result int

    if i <= j {
        result = i
    } else {
        result = j
    }

    if result >= 0 {
        return result
    }

    return 0
}
```

[Input data](https://pastebin.com/SjdwgKig)  test fails on. And [the answer should be.](https://pastebin.com/UhjsR8K3)

Comment: I don't think initializing with maxInt is a good idea, if you add something to it it wraps around. I would initialize with 0 and treat 0 as undefined. MinOrZero looks suspicious, if one number is negative it returns 0, but should probably return the non-negative number and if both numbers are negative (if that can happen) it should return maxInt I guess.

Comment: @maraca MinOrZero function was supposet to handle negative prioces which never appear actually. Even being bugged the function does not seem to influe. Probably :)
As of MaxInt - I tried to use it as  Infinity. Unfortunately lunch price may be 0-cost so using 0 as Inf can not be reliable, I think. I am sorry I did not mention limitations. I added that information into description.

Comment: I see. Then I would use -1 as undefined. The code gets a little more ugly because you always have to check for it, but I think it is still less confusing. In JS I actually use the dp array more like a hash map than an array, which could also be an option, then you know exactly which keys are defined. Or null and boxed values, guess that's a thing in Go too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to return the days on which the coupons were used you need to keep track of the best path and then you can go backwards at the end.

You have to be very careful when tickets are used or gained because it shifts the position in the dp array. Some positions can stay undefined. E.g. if you get a ticket on the first day then the cell corresponding to 0 tickets stays undefined, because the costs for the day are put at 1 tickets (and if the price is above 100 the next day we end up with 0 or 2 tickets, but not with 1). If that jumping up and down is done correctly it should work.

```js
function solve(prices) {
  const dp = [[]], n = prices.length
  let tickets = prices[0] > 100 ? 1 : 0
  dp[0][tickets] = {cost: prices[0]}
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    dp.push([])
    let t = prices[i] > 100 ? 1 : 0
    // not using tickets
    for (let j = 0; j <= tickets; j++)
      if (dp[i - 1][j])
        dp[i][j + t] = {cost: dp[i - 1][j].cost + prices[i], prev: j}
    // using tickets
    for (let j = 1; j <= tickets; j++)
      if (dp[i - 1][j] && (!dp[i][j - 1] || dp[i][j - 1].cost > dp[i - 1][j].cost))
        dp[i][j - 1] = {cost: dp[i - 1][j].cost, prev: j}
    tickets += t
  }
  // min has to be at 0 or 1 ticket
  let idx = dp[n - 1][0] && (!dp[n - 1][1] || dp[n - 1][0].cost <= dp[n - 1][1].cost) ? 0 : 1
  console.log('costs: ' + dp[n - 1][idx].cost)
  const days = []
  for (let day = n - 1; day > 0; day--) {
    if (dp[day][idx].prev > idx)
      days.unshift(day)
    idx = dp[day][idx].prev
  }
  console.log('days: ' + days)
}

solve([88,55,101,77,44,130,160,22,55,97,101,2,88])
```

Comment: works like a charm, but coupon days items should increase by 1 so input `[101, 101]` should give `days: 2` not `days: 1` 
So `days.unshift(day + 1)` seems to do the job. Thank you much